# Garbage collection pauses; Javascript

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, 2d, lag, tile

I've been working on creating a basic 2D tiled game and have been unable to pinpoint the source of noticeable pauses lasting ~100-200ms every second or two, but it seems like GC pauses as when I profiled my app, each game loop is taking around 4ms with a target of 60fps, which means it is running well within the required limit (16ms).

As far as I am aware, I have moved my object variables outside the functions that use them so they never go out of scope and therefore should not be collected, but I am still getting pauses.

Each game loop, the tiles are simply moved 1px to the left (to show smoothness of game frames), and apart from that, all that is called is this draw map function: (NOTE, these functions are defined as part of my engine object at startup so is this true that these functions are not created then collected each time they are called?).

```
engine.map.draw = function () {
    engine.mapDrawMapX = 0;
    engine.mapDrawMapY = 0;

    // Just draw tiles within screen (and 1 extra on both x and y boundaries)
    for (engine.mapDrawJ = -1; engine.mapDrawJ <= engine.screen.tilesY; engine.mapDrawJ++) {
        for (engine.mapDrawI = -1; engine.mapDrawI <= engine.screen.tilesX; engine.mapDrawI++) {
            //calculate map location (viewport)
            engine.mapDrawMapX = engine.mapDrawI + engine.viewport.x;
            engine.mapDrawMapY = engine.mapDrawJ + engine.viewport.y;

            engine.mapDrawTile = (engine.currentMap[engine.mapDrawMapY] && engine.currentMap[engine.mapDrawMapY][engine.mapDrawMapX]) ? engine.currentMap[engine.mapDrawMapY][engine.mapDrawMapX] : '';
            engine.tile.draw(engine.mapDrawI, engine.mapDrawJ, engine.mapDrawTile);
        }
    }
};
```

And the method called to draw each tile is:

```
engine.tile.drawTile = new Image(0,0);
engine.tile.draw = function (x, y, tile) {
    if ('' != tile) {
        engine.tile.drawTile = engine.tile.retrieve(tile); //this returns an Image() object
        engine.context.drawImage(engine.tile.drawTile,
            x * TILE_WIDTH + engine.viewport.offsetX,
            y * TILE_HEIGHT + engine.viewport.offsetY,
            TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);
    } else {
        engine.context.clearRect(x * TILE_WIDTH, y * TILE_HEIGHT, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);
    }
};
```

As per request, here are the store and retrieve functions:

```
engine.tile.store = function (id, img) {
    var newID = engine.tile.images.length;
    var tile = [id, new Image()];
    tile[1] = img;
    engine.tile.images[newID] = tile; // store
};

engine.tile.retrieveI;
engine.tile.retrieve = function (id) {
    //var len = engine.tile.images.length;

    for (engine.tile.retrieveI = 0; engine.tile.retrieveI < engine.tile.images.length; engine.tile.retrieveI++) {
        if (engine.tile.images[engine.tile.retrieveI][0] == id) {
            return engine.tile.images[engine.tile.retrieveI][1]; // return image
        }
    }
    //return null;
};
```

Comment: What does `engine.tile.retrieve(tile)` do? What's its code?

Comment: Added the code to the question for you. It returns an Image()

Comment: Can you put up a simple demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: I've written it in a visual studio solution for windows 8 metro. Is it possible to upload it to this site? If not, I'll try setting it up as an html page.

Comment: After changing it to an html file, I've noticed that the pauses are almost negligible in IE10, but the framerate is horrible in firefox. I would've thought IE10 would perform the same as metro, but apparently not.